# DynamoDB elements are not showing up in React app Material-Table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, material-ui, amazon-dynamodb

I have a React App hosted locally on my Mac. I am using Material-Table to organize my data and a serverless backend. I have my data stored in a DynamoDB table (4000 rows) and I am using Amplify, API Gateway and Lambda for endpoints and requests.

I am experiencing a strange issue, only about 2,023 rows are showing up in the Material-Table however there are 4000 rows in DynamoDB. When I added 1000 extra rows to Dynamo the Material-Table only shows 1,950 rows. I am very confused about this.

I thought it could be that the provisioned setting in Dynamo was limiting how much I was able to see in the Material-Table. But I changed the plan to "On-Demand" and still having the same problem.

I attached one image of the material-table count, and the dynamodb count for comparison.

Here is the Get function I have in my react app:

```
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/products`);
        const products = res.data;
        this.setState({products: products});

    }catch (err){
        console.log(`an error has occured while getting2: ${err}`);
    }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getProdFromDB();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Also there are No Errors in the Console.

[image][image]

Here is my Lambda Function for getting the items.

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    let responseBody = '';
    let statusCode = 0;

    const params = {
        TableName: "Products"
    };

//document scan , you can set filter expressions
    try {
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
        statusCode = 200;

    } catch(err) {
        responseBody = `Unable to get product: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;

    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
        },
        body: responseBody
    };
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run dynamodb query or scan, try check on the response. If there is LastEvaluatedKey on the result, then you should make next query or scan including ExclusiveStartKey on the params to pull the next items.

See these samples :

[Scan with ExclusiveStartKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan)

Please check it out for full doc of usage :

[Dynamodb Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property)

[Dynamodb Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added my lambda function I am using to get the items from the DB.

Comment: This led me down the right path. Now I am trying to update my Lambda function to scan all items.

Comment: I made some progress and posted a followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868585/lambda-function-to-paginate-dynamodb-node-js